# How to play a presentation with Powerpoint object model

Tags: c#, powerpoint, object-model

I want to play a presentation that I am controlling and managing via the Powerpoint Object automation model. Pouwerpoint 2013.
I expected the Presentation object to have a play or run method, but it does not.
is it possible to do this, and if so, how?
To be clear I want to do something like:

```
var app = new Powerpoint.Application();
var presentation = app.Presentations.Open(filename);
ManipulateStuffInPresentation(presentation);
presentation.Run();
```

But there is no Run method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
presentation.SlideShowSettings.Run();
```